# xcode report "libsystem_kernel.dylib __abort_with_payload" SIGABRT when call drawrect

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, drawrect

iOS app fired the SIGABRT event when calling drawRect ,

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__abort_with_payload:
    0x197660dc8 <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209
    0x197660dcc <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x197660dd0 <+8>:  b.lo   0x197660de8               ; <+32>
    0x197660dd4 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x197660dd8 <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x197660ddc <+20>: bl     0x197657a3c               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x197660de0 <+24>: mov    sp, x29
    0x197660de4 <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x197660de8 <+32>: ret
```

got fired when executing [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h)]; in the below codes,

```
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
    paragraph.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

    NSInteger length;
    if ((date.length + desc.length + name.length) - address.length > 0) {
        length = (date.length + desc.length + name.length);
    } else {
        length = address.length;
    }
    NSDictionary * textAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:WT_WhiteColor,
                                      NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:self.size.width / length],
                                      NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraph,
                                      NSShadowAttributeName:shadow,
                                      NSVerticalGlyphFormAttributeName:@0};

    CGSize textSize = [water_mark sizeWithAttributes:textAttributes];
    CGRect textFrame = CGRectMake(self.size.width - textSize.width - 40, self.size.height - textSize.height - 60, textSize.width, textSize.height);




    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size);
    int w = self.size.width;
    int h = self.size.height;
    NSLog(@"size of rect w: %i, h: %i", w,h);
    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h)];
    [water_mark drawInRect:textFrame withAttributes:textAttributes];
    UIImage * waterMarkedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return waterMarkedImage;
```

=======

The value of w is 3024, and the value of h is 4032, the xcode is 10.2.1, and the test iphone device is iphone 7 plus, with ios version of 12.3.1 .

Comment: The app runs smoothly on this part , until recently customer report the crash issue to me when applying watermark on photo taken. I can  reproduce it every time  on my xcode. I suspect it may relate to the lib versions . but no clue to fix it.

Comment: but if we apply the watermark on the photo selected from album, the code runs smoothly , no aborting.

Answer (score 1):

after add NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription to pinfo.list , the crash issue gone.